# Should Jupyter Notebook Take This Long to Run This Code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am watching a series of lectures on Python for mathematics students and the instructor quickly and conveniently runs the following code in Jupyter Notebook, but when I run this, It just writes Kernel Busy and produces no output:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

sym.init_printing()

x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')

display(x/y)
display(x**y)
display(np.sqrt(2))
display(sym.sqrt(2))
```

The system which I am currently using, is not a weak system. I am using Anaconda distribution and previously I was able to run the instructor's code as swiftly as he was. I have tried to run the code in Spyder and it did produce the expected result yesterday but now the same issue with Jupyter has arisen here. Restarting and interrupting the kernel has not been useful. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: No idea the problem (it runs fine for me). Try running it one line at a time to see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you try creating a new environment?

Comment: The problem is no error messages are shown, just an asterisk inside the brackets in front of In.